# How to get a specific column from the first row of a .csv file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am writing a bash script that connects to a server, exports data to a .csv file and then runs a jar that uses that newly created file. The problem is, the jar requires the file name to include the value of the Timestamp column of the first row in the .csv file.

Here is the first line of my .csv file. In this case, the timestamp is **2012-11-01** located at the end of the row.

```
"####<Nov 1, 2012 12:00:01 AM UTC> <Warning> <AesoRMQAdapter::RabbitMQAdapter> <> <myServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1351728001726> <BEA-000000> <DEBUG SEND MESSAGE={"Volume":55.1,"OfferedVolume":54.8,"ArmedVolume":0.0,"Status":false,"BlockNr":0,"Timestamp":"2012-11-01T00:00:01+0000"}> "
```

My question is as followed.

How can I, after retrieving the .csv file...

1. Grab the first timestamp from the first row in the .csv file
2. Use that timestamp in a filename that I'll be saving the .csv file under

I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `head -1` to get only one line from your input file, then `grep -o` to retrieve all timestamps in this line then `head -1` to keep only the first one.

```
$ date=`cat myfile.csv | head -1 | grep -o -e "[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}" | head -1`
$ echo $date
2012-11-01
$ mv myfile.csv myfile.$date.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, with `GNU grep`:

```
ts=$(grep -Pom1 '(?<="Timestamp":")[^"]*' csv)
```

or with `sed`:

```
ts=$(sed -n '1s/.*"Timestamp":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' csv)
```

Then you can do

```
mv csv "$ts.txt"
```

where `csv` is the old name, and `2012-11-01T00:00:01+0000.txt` will be the new name.

Comment: Will not work if there are two timestamps in the same line.  
    `echo '"Timestamp":"2012-10-12" "Timestamp":"2012-10-13"' | grep -Pom1 '(?<="Timestamp":")[^"]*'`

Comment: @jvivenot Only if both will be preceded with `"Timestamp":`. This possibility is not mentioned in the question. If this is possible, I'd ask the OP to confirm it. Anyway, in this case the `sed` version will return the last match, and the `grep` command can be piped to `tail -1` to get the last match as well. To get the first match, just add `1` at the end of `sed` command (`1s/.../.../1p`) or use `head -1` with `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

awk oneliner to do it in one shot:

```
awk -F':"' 'NR==1{split($NF,t,"T");print "mv "FILENAME" "t[1]".csv"}' file.csv
```

this will print the "mv" command line. if you want to execute it, just pipe the output to sh like:

```
awk ..... |sh
```

test:

```
kent$  cat dummy.csv 
"####<Nov 1, 2012 12:00:01 AM UTC> <Warning> <AesoRMQAdapter::RabbitMQAdapter> <> <myServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1351728001726> <BEA-000000> <DEBUG SEND MESSAGE={"Volume":55.1,"OfferedVolume":54.8,"ArmedVolume":0.0,"Status":false,"BlockNr":0,"Timestamp":"2012-11-01T00:00:01+0000"}> "
foo;bar;blah

kent$  awk -F':"' 'NR==1{split($NF,t,"T");print "mv "FILENAME" "t[1]".csv"}' dummy.csv
mv dummy.csv 2012-11-01.csv
```

Comment: This will fail if there are special characters in the filename.